# Change the color of a SVG inside <object>

Tags: html, css, object, svg, fill

How do I modify the color of a SVG image with CSS when it is inside an  tag? I have this image:

```
<object class="arrow" type="image/svg+xml" data="fotos/arrow.svg"></object>
```

and I tried to change its color in CSS like that but it's not working

```
.arrow {
    color:#B86e25;
    fill:#B86e25;
}
```

Comment: CSS can only affect inline SVG, not `<img>` or `<object>`.

Comment: you could inject the CSS into the object's document using javascript.

Comment: @Ortomala, one difference is that the other question assumes a JavaScript runtime.  It would be nice to have a portable solution (that doesn't depend on client-side scripting).